# How to improve restoring the PostgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to restore the PostgreSQL database from a dump. The below command works fine for me:

```
CALL "%PGBIN%\pg_restore" -c -d NetCatalog %DUMPFILE%
```

How can I add a few lines to my .bat file to rename the existing NetCatalog to NetCatalog_Old and create a new database NetCatalog before calling the above line?

PS. Is there an argument that allows me to log the restoring process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
psql -U postgres -d postgres -c "DROP DATABASE netcatalog_old"
psql -U postgres -d postgres -c "ALTER DATABASE netcatalog RENAME TO netcatalog_old"
```

You can redirect the info output of the restore like

```
pg_restore ... > my_log_file.txt
```

If you add the "-v" flag you can get more details of what's happening, but probably too much.